# How to get reference to Metamask account from Node.js

Tags: node.js, ethereum, solidity, web3js, metamask

i'm building -with my team- a dapp . 
we will be using Ethereum . 
So , when running code on the frontend with Web3.js , everything works fine but one of the requirements is to run it from the backend since it's related to a MongoDB database and it has a bunch of heavy treatments that need to be done on server-side

```
 if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
    web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
} else {
    web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
}
```

running this code on Node.js always results that it goes to the else block and that's not what we want . 
Is there any method to get current Metamask reference with node.js ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

MetaMask is a browser extension. So no, you can't access it from the backend, where you're not running a browser.

Comment: Hello smarx , thank you for your answer . i'm aware of that and that's why i'm asking for help 
Is it possible to pass the account id to the backend and make transactions with it ? 
thank you

Comment: You can only send transactions for an account for which you hold the private key. You could certainly send the account's address to your server, but your server won't have the private key. That's safely locked away in MetaMask to protect the user from developers getting access to it. :-)

Comment: @user94559 Just to add that you CAN get the private key to your account from Metamask, specifically for this purpose.